# parse xml with namespaces with gdata xml

Tags: objective-c, ios, gdataxml

i am developping an ios application and i am parsing my xml with gdataxml, but i am doing it wrong, my nslog is null

```
NSError *error = nil;
GDataXMLDocument *xmlResult = [[GDataXMLDocument alloc] initWithData:data options:0 error:&error];
if (error) {
    NSLog(@"%@",error);
}
```

NSLog(@"%@",xmlResult.rootElement);
   my root element is perfect, the error is with tempArray

```
NSArray *tempArray = [xmlResult nodesForXPath:@"//message/error/value" error:&error];
```

NSLog(@"mon array %@",tempArray);

my array is null,

my xml is like this :

```
<message xmlns="http://.....Api" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/....">
<error i:nil="true"/>
<value>
```

i am sur that my problème is with the namespace, but i don't how to do it ?

thanks for your answer

Comment: any idea why this did't work ?

Comment: Have you already fixed the problem here? There is a bunch of things that I don't know about GDataXML so this is really interesting.

Comment: hello samir, i am not able to get the elements from nodesForXPath , it returns an error like XPath error : Undefined namespace prefix
xmlXPathEval: evaluation failed
i need your help... stuck here from last 3 days and i dont want to used namespace paramerter so is it possible for me to do that ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After some testing with GDataXMLNode, here is my answer:

```
NSArray *tempArray = [xmlResult nodesForXPath:@"//_def_ns:message/_def_ns:error/_def_ns:value" error:&error];
```

You can see this comment in GDataXMLNode.h:

```
// This implementation of nodesForXPath registers namespaces only from the
// document's root node.  _def_ns may be used as a prefix for the default
// namespace, though there's no guarantee that the default namespace will
// be consistenly the same namespace in server responses.
```

It states that you can actually use **_def_ns** as your namespace. However, you can also set your own namespace in case there are other namespaces in your document.

```
NSDictionary *myNS = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                      @"http://.....Api", @"ns1",
                      @"http://.....Other_Api", @"ns2", nil];
NSArray *tempArray = [xmlResult nodesForXPath:@"//ns1:message/ns1:error/ns1:value" namespaces:myNS error:&error];
```

Comment: hello yoninja, i got error like XPath error : Undefined namespace prefix  xmlXPathEval: evaluation failed.  when i used nodesForXPath.

Comment: Hi @TapanNathvani, can you show me how you did it? Or maybe you can post a question regarding this. Thanks!

Comment: hello yonija,.. i solved that issue. Thanks for your reply. Here is my question link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17232712/gdataxmldocument-nodesforxpath-return-an-error   Thanks for your reply