# GDataXml and namespaces

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xpath, gdataxml

I am using GDataXML to parse may XML, but i have a probleme with this :

```
<....
                       <images xmlns:a="http://.../Arrays">
                           <a:string>http://images...233/Detail.jpg</a:string>
                           <a:string>http://images....233/Detail2.jpg</a:string>
                       </images>
                   .../>
```

i would like to have all the URL of my images and put it in an NSArray,i am doing like this :

```
NSError *error = nil;
    GDataXMLDocument *xmlResult = [[GDataXMLDocument alloc] initWithData:data options:0 error:&error];
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"%@",error);
    }


.......

NSArray *array = [... nodesForXPath:@"images" namespaces:a error:&error];
```

my array it's not null

Now i would like to access my url of images but i can not, i am doing like this:

```
arrar = [array elementsForName:@"a"];
```

byt my array is null, i think that the problemm is with namespaces wut i don't konw how to resolve it
Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1):

I think this question is related to this: [parse xml with namespaces with gdata xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9100040/parse-xml-with-namespaces-with-gdata-xml/9411766#9411766). Checkout my answer. Hope it helps! :)